# Does 'pretended not to see me' have the same meaning as 'pretended that he didn't see me' in this sentence?

Tags: infinitives, auxiliary-verbs

I really can't understand why in the following sentence I don't need to use the auxiliary verb do:

> He pretended not to see me to avoid an awkward situation.

Does

> He pretended that he didn't see me to avoid an awkward situation.

Has same meaning and is correct?

Comment: In your second example, you need to insert "he" after "that". Also, have a look at this link regarding *verb + infinitive* and *verb + 'that'*: http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/verbs-followed-infinitives/ .

Comment: In the first example, you are negating an infinitival clause: 'to see me' ~ 'not to see me'. In the second, 'that' introduces a finite content clause where the lexical verb 'see' requires _do_ support + 'not' to form the negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> He pretended not to see me to avoid an awkward situation.

This sentences uses negative infinitive. Negative infinitives are made by putting **not** before the **to+infinitive**.

After many verbs you can use infinitives as well as negative infinitives. That sentence means:

*He pretended that he didn't see me to avoid an awkward situation.*

Your second sentence is not grammatical because it lacks a subject. In other words, **that** is a conjunction which relates two clauses. You should put a subject after **that**.

---

**Note:** This answer is related to the **original** question not to the edited version.

Comment: Uh... Isn't "he", immediately after "that", the second subject?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes What do you mean?

Comment: You say that the second is ungrammatical because the bit after "that" doesn't have a subject. I'm presently sure the word immediately after "that" is the subject.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Oh, OP changed the question. In the original question there was no "he" at all in the second sentence.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that the second sentence was *quoting* the question, not correcting it.